# Error:- scaffolding + exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Below mentioned error I got when I was trying to scaffolding the code in my asp.net MVC 4.7.2 web application

> There was an error running the selected code generator: ‘Exception has
> been thrown by the target of an invocation.’

So many suggestion are there, after hours to find but nothing work so finally I got the solution which is unique so I would like to share here so that it will help someone.